# why are my if statements not causing the action to be performed

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making a simple rock paper scissors game in python using tkinter, i am taking the data from the entry and comparing it to what the computer has generated to perform a task, howver it is not printing 'draw' in the terminal when i input the same choice as the randomly generated one, and i haven't been able to find any issues with my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
#make window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

possible_actions = ['rock','paper','scisors']
computer_action = random.choice(possible_actions)
print(computer_action)


Label1 = Label(root, text="rock paper or scissors")
Label1.place(x=130 ,y=30)

entry1 = Entry(root, width = 20)
entry1.place(x=130, y =70)
entry1.pack
text1 = entry1.get

def button1_command():
if text1 == 'rock' and computer_action == 'rock':
    print('draw')
if text1 == 'scisors' and computer_action == 'scisors':
    print('draw')
if text1 == 'paper' and computer_action == 'paper':
    print('draw')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shorter code - `if text1 == compuer_action: print('Draw')`

Comment: The pack is not called, and in conflict with using place. So remove it. Also this is not a complete and verifiable example, the button1_command is wrongly indented, and not used.

Comment: @TDG: in this case that won't work because `text1` isn't a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect when the entry text is edited, then call the `button1_command()` function:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
#make window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

possible_actions = ['rock','paper','scisors']
computer_action = random.choice(possible_actions)
print(computer_action)


Label1 = Label(root, text="rock paper or scissors")
Label1.place(x=130 ,y=30)

entry1 = Entry(root, width = 20)
entry1.place(x=130, y =70)

def button1_command(e):
    text1 = entry1.get()
    if text1 == 'rock' and computer_action == 'rock':
        print('draw')
    if text1 == 'scisors' and computer_action == 'scisors':
        print('draw')
    if text1 == 'paper' and computer_action == 'paper':
        print('draw')

entry1.bind("<Return>", button1_command)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, `text1` must be a variable that works inside that function, because the input is modified after the variable is instantiated, so if its global it wont update to the correct values.

Comment: `entry1.pack` - the function isn't getting called, so why is this line there?

Comment: @the-thonnu You're right, I deleted that line as it doesn't affect the code behavior.

Comment: it is having and issue with the def button1_command(e):

Answer (score 1):

the solution is pretty easy, you need to use `get()` instead of `get`.
Also you didn't call the function to check the response...
I have re-created your code and added a button which calls the function when clicked.

```
def button1_command():
    text1 = entry1.get()
    if text1 == 'rock' and computer_action == 'rock':
        print('draw')
    if text1 == 'scisors' and computer_action == 'scisors':
        print('draw')
    if text1 == 'paper' and computer_action == 'paper':
        print('draw')

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
#make window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

possible_actions = ['rock','paper','scisors']
computer_action = random.choice(possible_actions)
print(computer_action)


Label1 = Label(root, text="rock paper or scissors")
Label1.pack()

entry1 = Entry(root, width = 20)
entry1.place(x=130, y =70)
entry1.pack()
Button(root, text="Check", command=button1_command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also you need to fetch the value of `text1` inside the function, because if doing it outside, it will store the value of entry widget when it is created (which will be empty as the user hasn't entered anything)...

I have used `pack()` for simplicity, you can also use `place()`

Comment: @Amar-SB please mark it as accepted if it worked, so other people having similar issue get their solution fast